# Disabling XML schema validation for SOAP Proxy APIs in Bluemix API Management

Tags: api, ibm-cloud, ibm-api-management

I published a SOAP API that is based on a WSDL. However, I need to disable the content validation for that API. I was able to disable the content validation for DataPower Web Services Proxy, but I cannot find this option for API Management in Bluemix. How do I disable it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The API Gateway does not execute schema validation in the SOAP request. The API Gateway only checks for well-formed XML  as the SOAP message must be parsed. This capability of checking for well-formed XML cannot be disabled.